# Xpages-Data Table: On Click Event on Link if the Link has a specific label value

Tags: javascript, datatable, xpages, alert, lotus-notes

on my Xpage, i have a data table in which i load data from an array (arrayPerson)

[a busy cat http://de.share-your-photo.com/img/1bf1672dec.jpg](http://de.share-your-photo.com/img/1bf1672dec.jpg)

In the first Column i have a link field (core control) from which i get different names.

**What i try to solve is:** 
If the Name is for Example "Thomas" i want to link to google.de
But if the Name is "Katrin" i want to pop up a alert window with text in it e.g. alert.("No Link")) and no link to google, only the alert

```
<xp:link escape="true" id="link1">
<xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:arrayPerson[0]}]]>  </xp:this.text>
</xp:link>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set link's `value` to URL only if your condition e.g. *arrayPerson[0] == 'Thomas'* is true. Otherwise return an empty string (= click on link does "nothing").

Render an `onclick` event with client side code if the condition is opposite *arrayPerson[0] != 'Thomas'*. This executes the CSJS code with the alert box on click only if the rendered condition is true:

```
<xp:link
    escape="true"
    text="#{javascript:arrayPerson[0]}"
    id="link1"
    value="#{javascript:arrayPerson[0] == 'Thomas' ? 'http://www.google.de' : ''}">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="false"
        rendered="#{javascript:arrayPerson[0] != 'Thomas'}"
        script="alert('No Link')">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

One is to use the Events panel. Enter your if statement in the Client-Side event box. If the outcome of any Client-Side code is a boolean true value, Server-Side code runs. Otherwise Server-Side code doesn't run. So return true without an alert for "Thomas", but for "Katrin", give the alert then return false.

The other option is to compute the value property of the link. You'll compute by writing Server-Side JavaScript, but the result needs to be a **string that can be parsed as Client-Side JavaScript**, see example below. That's a big gotcha, but once you understand that, it's not too bad unless you need to output lots of CSJS.

```
<xp:this.value>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:if (arrayPerson[0]=="Katrin") {
return "alert('No Link');";
}
</xp:this.value>
```

Comment: I´ve tried your 2 option, but when i click on the Katrin-Link, the browser trys to open
http://www.servername.com/alert('No Link')

Comment: Sorry, I think the return needs to be "javascript:alert('No Link');" to run as Client-Side JavaScript. value property returns the content for the anchor tag's href property, which is not initially CSJS but can be run CSJS

Comment: Option one is my preferred method - it's harder to get wrong because you're coding CSJS using a CSJS editor. Either return false or use No Submission to prevent it running a partial refresh.